# Error border TextFormField is of double width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing an ui issue with TextFormField error border in focused state.

When I tapped inside TextFormField, width is getting double on focus as below screen shot

[image]

Could you please guide me what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, this is a material design behavior, if you want to disable it , try this:

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              label: Text('label'),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,// <--- add this
            ),
          ),
```